# Binary Search Tree in Java using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to write an array implementation of Binary Search Trees in Java. To that end, I have the following two methods that are responsible for making sure all the data gets added into the array properly

```
private int[] testData = {50, 25, 75, 10, 15, 5, 53, 29, 79, 78, 111, 33};
private int[] tree = new int[100];
private final int ROOT = tree.length / 2; //Root is at the center of the array

public void insert(int key)
{
    if(tree[ROOT] == 0)
    {
        tree[ROOT] = key;
    }
    else
    {
        int locToInsert = findLocationToInsert(ROOT, key);
        if(locToInsert == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Tree branch full");
        }
        else
        {
            tree[locToInsert] = key;
        }
    }
}

public int findLocationToInsert(int c, int key)
{
    if(tree[c] != 0) //If current c is not empty
    {
        if(key > tree[c]) //Go right to find an empty c
        {
            findLocationToInsert(c + c/2, key);
        }
        else //Go left to find an empty c
        {
            findLocationToInsert(c - c/2, key);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

However, my recursive findLocationToInsert method always returns the root. How do I fix this implementation to return the first empty location it finds?

Comment: you forgot `return` before `findLocationToInsert`

Comment: Also, I don't see how the math here works out.  `c/2` is going to produce different numbers depending on whether you go left or right.  That can' be right.  Look instead [how a Heap is implemented.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive function doesn't do anything with the results of its recursive calls.

```
       findLocationToInsert(c + c/2, key);
```

As you can see, you are not assigning the returned value to anything, so it is just discarded.

So after your `if` or your `else` is executed, it simply goes to the line `return c` and returns the original `c` that it got - which is the root.

Before you decide what you want to do with the values of the recursive call, you should take care of another problem: you don't have a stop condition.

If you actually fill your tree, you are supposed to return `-1` according to your other method. But there is no place in your function that returns a `-1`. If the tree is full it's going to get stuck in an endless loop and you'll get a stack overflow.